# Need to reset OS X terminal AFTER logging out of Ubuntu (ssh + zsh)

Tags: macos, ubuntu, ssh, zsh, terminal.app

I have a problem I cannot understand, and cannot debug for the life of me.

- I run Mac OS X 10.9.2 (latest) and use Terminal.app and zsh as my shell.
- A server I work remotely on runs Ubuntu 13.04 and zsh as my shell.
- My $TERM environment variable on OS X is set to `xterm256-color`, and the same shows after logging into the remote server.
- Locally, my prompt is `[[ ${EUID} != 0 ]] && PS1=$'%{\e[1;32m%}%n@dhm %{\e[1;36m%}%1d %#%{\e[0m%} '`. I think the color codes are escaped properly.
- In my `.vimrc`:

  - `set nocompatible        " default options`
  - `set term=ansi           " colors on`
  - `syntax on               " syntax highlighting`
  - ...
- At the moment, I'm triaging the issue and my remote .zshrc is empty: `# Created by newuser for 5.0.0` is the only line in the file.

Here's my issue:

- When I use `vim` normally on my Mac, it works fine.
- When I ssh into the Ubuntu server, `vim` and `zsh` and etc. work fine.
- After I log out of the remote server, `vim` does the thing where arrow keys put `B\n` `A\n`, `C\n`, `D\n` that is usually fixed by, e.g., setting `nocompatible` or setting your terminal to `ansi`, according to other threads.
- After a terminal `reset` locally, `vim` works fine.

Another data point: this does not happen when I set my remote shell to `bash`. Even though my remote `.zshrc` is empty.

Any advice as to how I can debug this? I have tried things like comparing `env` and `echo $PS1` before and after `ssh`, but didn't find any changes.

Edit: I have posted a `gist` of the output of the login process through `script` here: https://gist.github.com/dhalperi/d00f191801c000ff0770

Comment: Althought the user's zshrc on the remote machine is empty, there might be some conflicting code in system wide config files (`/etc/zsh*`, `/etc/zlogout`, etc.)

Comment: Is `script` available on OS X? If so, you could try to make a hardcopy of the process login->logout and check if some non-visible characters are transmitted.

Comment: @mpy - Edited to post the `typescript` in a gist

Comment: 1. Can you please try answering `0` to that question? So as to avoid having that process start. 2. The right way to debug shells is to run them with `-x`, try `ssh foo@your-address.org -t 'zsh -x'` (and save that in script). Although it is a little noisy, you should be able to find the source of any funny characters.

Comment: Ok. A better idea: *after* you answered '0' there to have an empty `.zshrc`. Try `ssh foo@bar.com -t 'zsh --no-global-rcs'`. This will start zsh skipping any of the system configuration files, i.e. those in `/etc`. If you use `ssh foo@bar.com -t 'zsh -f'` you'll ignore all of your own config files. Worth trying as well.